# Add to an array while in a loop with a key

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to populate all the links in my database into an array with a key something like this:

```
$link = array(99999 => "http://link1.com", 111111 => "http://link2.com");
```

Which returns:

> Array ( [99999] => http://link1.com [111111] => http://link2.com )

How can i get the array to look like that when going through a loop, Here is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $link[] = "$row[r_id] => $row[r_link]";
}
```

It returns:

> Array ( [0] => 24004 => http://link1.com [1] => 30554 =>
>   http://link2.com

But i don't wan't it to be like this, How can i get it the same as the first example while going through a loop ?

Comment: "with a key something like this" - your description couldn't be more vague than that...

Comment: Well the top bit is what i want it to look like, But mine is looking like the bottom code when going through a loop.

Comment: you know, if you have picked the same numbers, it would have made a lot more sense...

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $link[$row['r_id']] = $row['r_link'];
}
```

Comment: @user3173526 what about accepting EricSchaefer's answer then?

Answer (score 0):

```
$link[$row['r_id']] = $row['r_link'];
```